# how to pass id aslast part of url in next.js

Tags: next.js

i am trying to make id the last part of url but i dont know the syntaxt can any one help me out        `<Link href="query/{itm._id}">`  in next js

```
{Items.map((itm)  => ( 
          <Link href="query/{itm._id}">
        <Alert className="question13">{itm.Name}</Alert>
        </Link>
      ))}
```

i am trying to make id the last part of url but i dont know the syntaxt can any one help me out        `<Link href="query/{itm._id}">`  in next js

Comment: ```href={`/query/${encodeURIComponent(itm._id)}`}``` -- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals, https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/link#if-the-route-has-dynamic-segments

Answer (score 2):

```
<Link
  href={{
    pathname: `/query`,
    query: {
      id: item.id,
    },
  }}
>
</Link>
```

Answer (score 2):

The syntax should be like this
since you are dealing with dynamic route then your `href` should be enclosed with ``` {``} ```  and the variable should be give like `${var_name}` in your case link should look like this:

```
<Link href={`query/${itm._id}`}>
```

Answer (score 1):

Submit the parameters this way

```
<Link
      href={{ pathname: "/mypage", query: { id: item.id } }}
    >
<Alert className="question13">{itm.Name}</Alert>
</Link>
```

And this way you get the parameters

```
import { useRouter } from "next/router";
function mypage() {
 const router = useRouter();
 console.log(router.query);
}
export default mypage;
```

Comment: if i do like this will the urls be crawled by google bots?

Answer (score 0):

```
import { useRouter } from 'next/router'

const Post = () => {
  const router = useRouter()
  const { id } = router.query

  return <p>Post: {id}</p>
}

export default Post
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?